# i want to record and playback a window that is generated from a gridview cell hyperlink in Coded UI Testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have an aspx page that contains a gridview. One of the gridview cells is a hyperlink that opens a window (client script) and have some mandatory data.

When I record all this scenario in UI test builder, it finishes without any problem but if I playback this, the hyperlink can be clicked and opens the form but it then fails and gives the error: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties.

I'm using VS 2012premuim and C#.

Comment: There are several Microsoft pages on debugging techniques for Coded UI. You might start by searching for the "Coded UI content index".

Comment: how can i reach the controls in the window opened by the hyperlink?

Comment: The properties CUIT uses to search for your control are probably not the same in every instance of the control. When playback fails use AccExplorer or the test builder's crosshair function to see the control's current properties and check if any are different from the ones set for search properties in the UIMap.

Answer (score 0):

When you done your Coded UI test record maybe the location of you app was different, or the location of the control you are trying to assert has changed. Make sure that every time you start the application it is in the same position and also the location of the controls you are trying to validate.

Comment: Screen position is very unlikely to be a significant problem. Coded UI searches for controls independently and does not use screen locations.

Comment: I also mentioned the location of the controls, not only the location of the app.

Comment: i am 100% sure for the location of the controls. the problem is with the hyperlink (button) that is a gridview cell and when i searched, Coded UI test tracks the cell but not the complex content inside. i what to know if there are any tricks to do this.